# Use a nested loop in JavaScript to generate spot art on top of each other

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

I want to generate colourful spot art using  JavaScript on the canvas element, but I am struggling with using the nested loop to make it happen. The output should look like an horizontal and vertical line of 10 spots of various colour.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  // Generate random colour 
  randomColour = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
  drawCircle(30, xPos, yPos, randomColour);
  xPos += 50;
}
yPos += 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply needed to add the outer for-loop. The outer for-loop is changing the y-value so that circles can be drawn to a new row. You should also set the x-value to zero in this loop so that drawing proceeds from left-to-right.

Here is the logic for both loops:

```
   for (var i =0; i < 10; i++)
{
    yPos += 50; 
    xPos = 0; 
    for(var j=0 ; j<10;j++)
    { 
        // Generate random colour 
        randomColour = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16); 
        console.log(randomColour); 
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(xPos + 20, yPos + 20, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = randomColour;
        ctx.fill(); 
        //drawCircle(30, xPos, yPos, randomColour); 
        xPos += 50; 
    } 
}
```

I have created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzJ9n/2/) for the sake of completion. Change the logic as you see fit.

If you are new to Javascript I suggest you read the tutorials and guides on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) It also includes documentation on how to use the canvas API.